# I want to populate a new range by inserting numbers between already populated range based on adjusacent cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to populate a new range and inserting numbers between already populated range based on adjacent cell value.

- Eg. if **Column A** has a range between **1 - 10**
- and in **Column B** I entered **3** against the number 4 of Column A
- then in **Column C** a new range should populate splitting 4 into 4a, 4b & 4c as I had entered 3 against it
- New list should generate like - **1, 2, 3, *4a, 4b, 4c*, 5, 6....**

Other examples are entered against no. 7 and 9 of Column A in the image attached.

Screenshot attached below:

[image: Screenshot of the suggestive output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:A&IFERROR(CHAR(96+SPLIT(IF(B2:B<>"", 
 REPT("♦1", B2:B), ), "♦")*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(B2:B))))), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), " ")))), ".?`$", )), "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image: 0]

---

fix for B2 value if 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:A&IFERROR(CHAR(96+SPLIT(IF(B2:B>1, 
 REPT("♦1", B2:B), ), "♦")*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(B2:B))))), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), " ")))), "\d+`$|`$", )), "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image: 0]

### [formula explanation / spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZqVBJLQvYjmmAd0xwrgDWG27Mr2cMF2v05eye10mIhQ/edit#gid=1304072327)

Comment: idea is simple, if B contains number repeat number 1 n-times and multiply it by max value of B column values so for row 5 there will be 1, 1, 1 multiplied by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 which results in 1, 2, 3, 0, 0. then to each value add CHAR(96) to get a, b, c, ', ' (e.g. character number 97 which is small a, char 98 which is b, char 99 = c, etc. then we merge A column values to each value (to get 4a) then we collapse all of it into one single cell with query(transpose(query(transpose( and split that cell string into separate values, remove duplicates with unique, remove residues with regex and query

Comment: Thanks a lot for this prompt help. 
This formula worked like a charm but it repeats 1 if anything is inserted against 1 in the Column B else it works fine. 

Then it gives - **1a, 1b, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1** 

Also It would be really helpful if you can explain this formula as well.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt help. I am a newbie in coding / google scripts, i just browse through the internet and take help from supportive people like you. Can you explain little in detail the breakup of the formula and the latest fix that you applied.

Comment: see explanation here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZqVBJLQvYjmmAd0xwrgDWG27Mr2cMF2v05eye10mIhQ/edit#gid=1304072327

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation.